# How to sort something with type of struct

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

I have a structure ElementType

```
typedef struct
{
    int AtomicNumber;
    char Name[31];
    char Symbol[4];
} ElementType;
```

I am trying to implement a sorting algorithm that will sort the elements alphabetically. I compare the strings but nothing works. I can't figure out what is wrong with my function below.

```
void sortAlphabetical(ElementType elements[NUM_ELEMENTS])
{
   printf("SORTING!\n");
   int c, d;
   for (c = 0 ; c < NUM_ELEMENTS - 1; c++)
   {
       for (d = 0 ; d < NUM_ELEMENTS - c - 1; d++)
       {
           if (elements[d].Name > elements[d+1].Name)
           {
                ElementType temp;

                temp.AtomicNumber = elements[d].AtomicNumber;
                strcpy(temp.Name, elements[d].Name);
                strcpy(temp.Symbol, elements[d].Symbol);

                elements[d].AtomicNumber = elements[d+1].AtomicNumber;
                strcpy(elements[d].Name, elements[d+1].Name);
                strcpy(elements[d].Symbol, elements[d+1].Symbol);

                elements[d+1].AtomicNumber = temp.AtomicNumber;
                strcpy(elements[d+1].Name, temp.Name);
                strcpy(elements[d+1].Symbol, temp.Symbol);
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: You cannot compare arrays or strings directly. Use `strcmp(elements[d].Name , elements[d+1].Name)` instead

Comment: Is `qsort` an option? No need for manual `strcpy` with this design, you could just assign structure elements `ElementType temp = elements[d]; elements[d] = elements[d + 1]; elements[d + 1] = temp;`

Comment: FYI: The element with the longest name is Rutherfordium (104, Rf), and its length is 13.  You could change the 31 in your structure to 16 (14 would be sufficient, but 16 won't change the size of the structure).  The symbol could be 3 characters for placeholder element names such as  "Ununquadium", atomic number 114, symbol Uuq.  This was before the element was actually discovered and given a 'proper' name — Flerovium, 114, Fl.  Flerovium (and Livermorium) were given names in 2012; Oganesson and 3 others were given names in 2016.  All the elements in the first 7 periods now have proper names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (elements[d].Name > elements[d+1].Name)
```

C's `>` operator isn't "smart" enough to compare strings in dictionary order; it's only for numbers or pointers. This condition actually just compares the `char*` pointers to the names' first characters.

Instead you would need the [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) function:

```
if (strcmp(elements[d].Name, elements[d+1].Name) > 0)
```

Also, instead of writing your own bubble sort, you might consider [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort), which is for exactly this sort of thing, is a bit easier to write, and may be faster for large arrays:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int compareElementNames(const void* p1, const void* p2)
{
    const ElementType *elem1 = p1;
    const ElementType *elem2 = p2;
    return strcmp(elem1->Name, elem2->Name);
}

void sortAlphabetical(ElementType elements[NUM_ELEMENTS])
{
    qsort(elements, NUM_ELEMENTS, sizeof(*elements), compareElementNames);
}
```